# Is it the best practice to use built in sort()function rather than merge sort whose complexity is always nlogn

Tags: algorithm, sorting, c++11, data-structures

worst case complexity of quick sort is n^2 and best n logn and heap sort and merge sort complexity is n logn both worst,best and average case.But heap sort is not stable in everywhere.Instead merge is stable.So merge is best.But built in sort() function is n logn and implementing  this, is more easier than merge sort while save time and energy.Is there any case where merge sort is apllied rather than this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[2000];
    int n=2000;
    for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
    {
        a[i]=rand()%3000;//taking elements randomly less than 3000
    }
    sort(a,a+n);//sort elements .is it best practice instead use of merge sort always

}
```

Comment: Just saying "they're both `O(n log n)` and one is stable" doesn't resolve the question of which is "best".  The big O complexity is a very crude measure of efficiency; in real life, the constant multiplier hidden within the big O can make a much greater difference.

Comment: Which is the best in actual practice

Comment: "Actual practice" is hugely broad and there isn't a single answer.  Generally, you should try using the standard `sort` first.  If you need a stable sort, use the standard `stable_sort`.  A custom-written algorithm *might* be better if there is something special about your data, but the only way to know for sure is to try it both ways and profile.  You can also read what the C++ standard guarantees about the complexity of the standard functions.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ 11, [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) is guaranteed to be stable, and if sufficient memory is available then it's O(n log n). If it needs additional memory then it's O(n log<sup>2</sup> n).

If you don't need a stable sort, then call [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), which is documented to be O(n log n).

As I understand it, `std::sort` and `std::stable_sort` often use something like [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), which uses Quicksort if possible, but falls back to something else if the Quicksort recursion depth becomes too deep.